# AVSpeechSynthesizer functionalities disappeared in a file porting

Tags: swift, avspeechsynthesizer

I included a Swift class using

> AVSpeechSynthesizer

and

> AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate

functionalities in another project and now they are all reported as undeclared types while the old project correctly resolves them.
Is there something other that should be done to the project to have them working I forgot to replicate in the new project, or what might be the problem?
[image]

Comment: You need to add the library including AVSpeechSynthesizer to your project.

Comment: I checked all libraries from the old project with the ones of the current one, and they completely match. At any rate I think a missing library produces a linking error, not a compiling one.

Comment: Any new idea on the issue?